# SSIS possible to read file path from database table parameter value?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to read file path from database table parameter values?

I have outgoing files which is using the flat file connection manager, how to define the file path to read from a database table parameter value?

I also have an incoming files which is using the foreach enumerator, how to define the file path to read from a database table parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

In a "Execute SQL Task", query the paths from your database table and assign the result to variables. Then use those variables in the connection manager connection string expression.